# Highcharts: Only animate pie size with donut graph / prevent innersize animation

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/ZENuS/

**Highcharts JS call:**

```
$(function () {
    $('div').highcharts({
        chart: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            margin: [0, 0, 0, 0]
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                minSize: 0,
                size: 500,
                animation: {
                    duration: 5000,
                    easing: 'linear'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            innerSize: 486,
            data: [1]
        }]
    });
});
```

As you can see in the fiddle, while the graph grows, the thickness of the line animates as well as the percentage of the circle it takes up. I'd like the line to stay the same thickness the whole time, and only change how much of the circle it fills. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Highcharts API only provides options to calibrate the `duration` and `easing` of this animation, as you've already seen. The default "scaling" animation into the charts final height/width and thickness of its "donut" cannot be altered.  You either have no animation (`animation: false`) or this "scaling" animation with control over the `duration` and `easing`. Like I said, these are the limitations that exist within the Highcharts API; I cannot speak to the feasibility of coming up with some magical workaround via the jQuery UI or any other framework.

**In summary:**
*no?*

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this option is not possible, but you can request your proposition on http://highcharts.uservoice.com/